# C# - Cannot implicitly convert type List<Product> to List<IProduct>

Tags: c#, interface, compiler-errors

I have a project with all my Interface definitions:  RivWorks.Interfaces
I have a project where I define concrete implmentations: RivWorks.DTO

I've done this hundreds of times before but for some reason I am getting this error now:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<RivWorks.DTO.Product>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<RivWorks.Interfaces.DataContracts.IProduct>'

Interface definition (shortened):

```
namespace RivWorks.Interfaces.DataContracts
{
    public interface IProduct
    {
        [XmlElement]
        [DataMember(Name = "ID", Order = 0)]
        Guid ProductID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        [DataMember(Name = "altID", Order = 1)]
        long alternateProductID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        [DataMember(Name = "CompanyId", Order = 2)]
        Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
        ...
    }
}
```

Concrete class definition (shortened):

```
namespace RivWorks.DTO
{
    [DataContract(Name = "Product", Namespace = "http://rivworks.com/DataContracts/2009/01/15")]
    public class Product : IProduct
    {
        #region Constructors
        public Product() { }
        public Product(Guid ProductID)
        {
            Initialize(ProductID);
        }
        public Product(string SKU, Guid CompanyID)
        {
            using (RivEntities _dbRiv = new RivWorksStore(stores.RivConnString).NegotiationEntities())
            {
                model.Product rivProduct = _dbRiv.Product.Where(a => a.SKU == SKU && a.Company.CompanyId == CompanyID).FirstOrDefault();
                if (rivProduct != null)
                    Initialize(rivProduct.ProductId);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private Methods
        private void Initialize(Guid ProductID)
        {
            using (RivEntities _dbRiv = new RivWorksStore(stores.RivConnString).NegotiationEntities())
            {
                var localProduct = _dbRiv.Product.Include("Company").Where(a => a.ProductId == ProductID).FirstOrDefault();
                if (localProduct != null)
                {
                    var companyDetails = _dbRiv.vwCompanyDetails.Where(a => a.CompanyId == localProduct.Company.CompanyId).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (companyDetails != null)
                    {
                        if (localProduct.alternateProductID != null && localProduct.alternateProductID > 0)
                        {
                            using (FeedsEntities _dbFeed = new FeedStoreReadOnly(stores.FeedConnString).ReadOnlyEntities())
                            {
                                var feedProduct = _dbFeed.AutoWithImage.Where(a => a.ClientID == companyDetails.ClientID && a.AutoID == localProduct.alternateProductID).FirstOrDefault();
                                if (companyDetails.useZeroGspPath.Value || feedProduct.GuaranteedSalePrice > 0)     // kab: 2010.04.07 - new rules...
                                    PopulateProduct(feedProduct, localProduct, companyDetails);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (companyDetails.useZeroGspPath.Value || localProduct.LowestPrice > 0)                // kab: 2010.04.07 - new rules...
                                PopulateProduct(localProduct, companyDetails);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private void PopulateProduct(RivWorks.Model.Entities.Product product, RivWorks.Model.Entities.vwCompanyDetails RivCompany)
        {
            this.ProductID = product.ProductId;
            if (product.alternateProductID != null)
                this.alternateProductID = product.alternateProductID.Value;
            this.BackgroundColor = product.BackgroundColor;
            ...
        }
        private void PopulateProduct(RivWorks.Model.Entities.AutoWithImage feedProduct, RivWorks.Model.Entities.Product rivProduct, RivWorks.Model.Entities.vwCompanyDetails RivCompany)
        {
            this.alternateProductID = feedProduct.AutoID;
            this.BackgroundColor = Helpers.Product.GetCorrectValue(RivCompany.defaultBackgroundColor, rivProduct.BackgroundColor);
            ...
        }
        #endregion

        #region IProduct Members
        public Guid ProductID { get; set; }
        public long alternateProductID { get; set; }
        public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
        ...
        #endregion
    }
}
```

In another class I have:

```
using dto = RivWorks.DTO;
using contracts = RivWorks.Interfaces.DataContracts;
...
public static List<contracts.IProduct> Get(Guid companyID)
{
    List<contracts.IProduct> myList = new List<dto.Product>();
    ...
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?  (And I am sure it is something trivially simple!)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Yep it's a covariance limitation in C#.  You can't convert a list of one type to a list of another.

Instead of:

```
List<contracts.IProduct> myList = new List<dto.Product>();
```

You have to do this

```
List<contracts.IProduct> myList = new List<contracts.IProduct>();

myList.Add(new dto.Product());
```

Eric Lippert explains why they implemented it this way:
http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/Covariance+and+Contravariance/default.aspx ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20100410234642/http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/Covariance+and+Contravariance/default.aspx))

(And why it is different than working with arrays of items).

Comment: Both Daniel and Kevin answered this, though in differing ways.  Bravo!  Fair explanation of contra/covariance.  It is indeed either IN **or** OUT but not both.  Having not used .NET 4.0 that slipped my mind completely!  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 42):

You can't do that.  If you have a `List<IProduct>`, you can put *any* `IProduct` in it.  So if you have a `Product2` which implements `IProduct` you could put it in the list.  But the original list was created as `List<Product>`, so anyone using the list would expect only objects of type `Product`, not `Product2` to be in the list.

In .NET 4.0, they added covariance and contravariance for interfaces, so you could convert `IEnumerable<Product>` to `IEnumerable<IProduct>`.  But this still doesn't work for lists, since the list interface allows you both to "put stuff in" and "get stuff out".

Comment: Nice tip about being able to use IEnumerable

Comment: I'm still a little confused by this part: 

> so anyone using the list would expect only objects of type Product, not Product2 to be in the list.

Why would the user make that assumption? If I am using something *declared* as List<IProduct>, I wouldn't expect to automatically be able to downcast elements to one implementation or another. 

(It's possible this is just a quirky choice I don't like by MSFT, but if not I really want to try to understand their reasoning.)

Comment: @EleanorHolley the reason is that this decision moves a run-time error to a compile-time error.

Comment: @whobetter Ah, you're right. I forgot about the strong type checks at runtime. I've spent too much time in ReScript.

Answer (score 5):

Just as a remark: [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) was added in C# 4.0.

Comment: But not supported in constructs that have both IN and OUT channels.  List<T> is such a construct so they do not support contra/covariance!

Comment: Yes, it would only work if using an IEnumerable<contracts.IProduct>

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can use this!

```
        class A {}
        class B : A {}
        ...
        List<B> b = new List<B>();
        ...
        List<A> a = new List<A>(b.ToArray());
```

Now, to give direct solution,

```
using dto = RivWorks.DTO;
using contracts = RivWorks.Interfaces.DataContracts;
...
public static List<contracts.IProduct> Get(Guid companyID) {
    List<dto.Product> prodList = new List<dto.Product>();
    ...
    return new List<contracts.IProduct>(prodList.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a little example how to do it.

```
    public void CreateTallPeople()
    {
        var tallPeopleList = new List<IPerson>
        {
            new TallPerson {Height = 210, Name = "Stevo"},
            new TallPerson {Height = 211, Name = "Johno"},
        };
        InteratePeople(tallPeopleList);
    }

    public void InteratePeople(List<IPerson> people)
    {
        foreach (var person in people)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{person.Name} is {person.Height}cm tall.  ");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this instead:

```
List<contracts.IProduct> myList = new List<contracts.IProduct>((new List<dto.Product>()).Cast<contracts.IProduct>());
```

Comment: seriously? do you know what that even means ?