# How to properly mock in .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, mocking, covariance, contravariance

This has to be trivial, but being quite new to TDD, I can't figure out the proper way to do it.

Let's say we have a WinForms application that, as part of its startup process, looks for DLLs in given folders to dynamically populate its main menu bar.

Those DLLs are mere plug-ins: they all implement an interface, and they all will be displayed as menu entries. It's really as simple as that.

Let's call each DLL a `Module`.

Now, I thought "Hey, Steve, you're gonna have to mock this `Module` objects. Let's define an interface named `IModule`, and make the `Module` class implement it. That way you can mock them as you please".

So, let me write a couple of lines of code, specifically `IModule` and `Module` (I'm writing this straight without the support of a compiler, so it might not compile):

```
<!-- language: c# -->

public interface IModule {
    string Id { get; }
    string DisplayName { get; }
}

public class Module : IModule {
    public string Id { get; }
    public string DisplayName { get; }
    public string Path { get; private set; }

    public Module(FileInfo path) {
        Path = path.FullName;
    }
}
```

And, while we are at it, let's implement the class that will do the actual loading:

```
public class ModuleLoader {
    IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> SearchPaths;

    public ModuleLoader(IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> searchPaths) {
        SearchPaths = searchPaths;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IModule> LoadModules() {
        var modules = SearchPaths
            .Where(dir => dir.Exists)
            .SelectMany(dir => dir.GetFiles("*.dll").Select(dll => new Module(dll)));
        return modules;
    }

}
```

Here comes the problem: `LoadModules()` won't compile because of—from what I could gather—variance issues.

The error message is as follows:

> Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Module> to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<IModule>

Which is the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640738/c-sharp-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-listproduct-to-listiproduct) question.

Now, there must be something trivial that escapes me. To the best of my knowledge, making `LoadModules()` return `IEnumerable<IModule>` qualifies as a Good Thing™. Changing the return type to `IEnumerable<Module>` of course makes the code compile, but it only moves the problem to the unit tests.

I'm a bit confused, and maybe I'm doing it all wrong (I apologize if that's the case).

So, how would you go about this? How do I make `Module` mockable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace `var` with `IEnumerable<IModule>` and replace `new Module(dll)` with `(IModule) (new Module(dll))`

Comment: So... that's it, huh? A simple cast. I really need a vacation. Thank you, @DevinB. The exact reason why I have to cast an instance of a class that implements a certain interface to that same interface is still somewhat unclear to me, I guess I'll really have to read up Eric Lippert's posts about variance. BTW, replacing `var` is not really needed, and I would be really surprised if it did. Thanks again.

Comment: I know replacing var isn't really needed, but it is best to be clear, especially in cases like this there the entire PROBLEM was that the LINQ query was returning an unexpected type. In cases such as this, clarity is by far the most important factor in finding and eliminating bugs.

Comment: Fair point, DevinB. Thank you very much. Now I can mock away :)