# Cannot implicitly convert type 'class' to 'interface'

Tags: inheritance, interface, linked-list

I have two projects that share code. The original source files are in project/namespace 'ns1'; which has a reference to project/namespace 'ns2'. I cannot add a reference in the other direction too as this would create a circular dependancy. To get around this I have added 'interface I' to 'ns2' by 'add as link' in Visual Studio.

This is basically the definitions of the shared code:

```
 namespace ns1
 {
    public interface I { }

    public class A : I { }
 }

 namespace ns2
 {
    using ns1;

    public class B : I { }
 }
```

If I then do this:

```
 namespace ns1
 {
    public class C
    {
       public method m()
       {
          List<I> list = new List<I>();
          list.Add(new A());
       }
    }
 }
```

Build succeeds. But if I do this:

```
 namespace ns1
 {
    using ns2;

    public class C
    {
       public method m()
       {
          List<I> list = new List<I>();
          list.Add(new B());
       }
    }
 }
```

Build fails - "Cannot implicitly convert type 'ns2.B' to 'ns1.I'".

Can someone please explain/offer a solution?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640738/c-sharp-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-listproduct-to-listiproduct