# Interface with object List<IAnotherInterface> - Is this possible?

Tags: c#, interface

Is it possible to define an interface where one of the objects is a list of another interface?

I have two EF objects:

=====

```
class ImageType1
{
    string Id
    string Name
    List<ImageType1Size> Sizes
}

class ImageType1Size
{
    string Id
    int Width
    int Height
}

class ImageType2
{
    string UserId
    string ImageId
    string Name
    List<ImageType2Size> Sizes
}

class ImageType2Size
{
    string UserId
    string ImageId
    int Width
    int Height
}
```

=====

For each of the image size classes, all of the properties are keys (just a side note).

Now, what I want to do is create the following two interfaces:

=====

```
interface IImage
{
    string Name
    List<ImageSize> Sizes
}

interface IImageSize
{
    int Width
    int Height
}
```

=====

In my project, I have created partials for ImageType1, ImageType1Size, ImageType2, and ImageType2Size, each using the respective interface.

I'm getting an error in trying to cast the Sizes property in ImageType1 and ImageType2 to use the interface IImageSize.

=====

Is this possible to do? If I'm not clear please let me know and I'll rephrase the question.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the exact line of code that gives you this error. It will be easier to articulate an answer after you provide that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider generics here:

```
interface IImage<TSize> where TSize : IImageSize
{
    List<TSize> Sizes { get; }
}

class ImageType1 : IImage<ImageType1Size>
{
    List<ImageType1Size> Sizes { get; private set; }
}
```

Alternatively, this would work:

```
interface IImage
{
    IEnumerable<IImageSize> Sizes { get; }
}

class ImageType1
{
    public List<ImageType1Size> SizeList { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<IImageSize> Sizes { get { return SizeList; } }
}
```

It depends on what works best for how you operate on the data.

Comment: I had ended up doing option 2. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since the signature of your ImageType1 class enforces that ImageType1.Sizes only contains ImageType1Size objects then storing a IImageSize inside of the ImageType1.Sizes is not allowed because that would allow for non ImageType1Size objects (ImageType2Size  for example) to be added to the list.

This means you cannot store any old IImageSize in a ImageType1.Sizes which is probably what you want.

You can still however still use ImageSize1 and ImageSize2 objects as if they were IImageSizes when doing other operations, for example

```
void Test()
{
    ImageType2 image = new ImageType2();
...
    foreach(var size in image.Sizes)
    {
        if(IsTooBig(size))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("I'm too big!")l
        }
    }
}

bool IsTooBig(IImageSize imagesize)
{
    return imagesize.Width > 500;
}
```

now you can use IsTooBig on both ImageType1Size and ImageType2Size objects.

Answer (score 0):

There's been a whole discussion on casting List to List before.

You can read up about it here, but the gist of it is that you can't do it in C#.

[C# - Cannot implicitly convert type List<Product> to List<IProduct>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640738/c-sharp-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-listproduct-to-listiproduct)

Answer (score 0):

`foreach (IImageSize iSize in list) { int iWid = iSize.Width; }`

Answer (score 0):

To build on what default.kramer said, if you explicitly need `IImage` as a type elsewhere, you can split the interface like so:

```
interface IImage
{
  string Name
}
interface IImage<TSize> : IImage where TSize : IImageSize
{
    List<TSize> Sizes { get; }
}

class ImageType1 : IImage<ImageType1Size>
{
    List<ImageType1Size> Sizes { get; private set; }
}
```

Without doing this, you can never have a bare `IImage` without specifying it's `TSize`.  Of course, if you need to be able to access the `Sizes` property of a non-generic `IImage`, you're going to need to add an extension method like this:

```
static class IImageHelper
{
  static List<IImageSize> GetSizes<TSize>(this IImage<TSize> image) where TSize: IImageSize
  {
    return image.Sizes.OfType<IImageSize>();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this can't be done. When reasoning why, it's helpful to consider your problem outside of an interface.

```
public void Example()
{
  List<ImageType1Size> Sizes1 = new List<ImageType1Size>();
  List<ImageType2Size> Sizes2 = new List<ImageType2Size>();
  List<IImageSize> Sizes;

  Sizes1 = Sizes; // These won't compile because the compiler can't guarantee that an
  Sizes2 = Sizes; // IImageSize is an ImageType1Size. It could be an ImageType2Size

  Sizes = Sizes1; // These will compile because the compiler knows that both 
  Sizes = Sizes2; // ImageType1Size and ImageType2Size are IImageSize's
}
```

Now you can compare this to your classes.

```
class ImageType1 : IImageType
{
  string Id {get; set;}
  string Name {get; set;}
  List<ImageType1Size> Sizes {get; set;} // This is just like Sizes1 = Sizes in the
                                         // example above.
}

public void Test(IImageSize imageSize)
{
  IImageType imageType = new ImageType1();

  imageType.Add(imageSize) // This would compile, as IImageType.Sizes will 
                           // take any IImageSize

  // But what really happens behind the interface is this:
  ((ImageType1)imageType)Sizes.Add(imageSize);    

  // Trying to insert an IImageSize into the collection
  // doesn't work, because the compiler can't guarantee that 
  // it's an ImageType1Size
}
```

Note: I'm assuming that your example showing

```
interface IImage
{
  string Name
  List<ImageSize> Sizes
}
```

Is actually supposed to be

```
interface IImage
{
  string Name
  List<IImageSize> Sizes
}
```

As you've not mentioned the type "ImageSize" elsewhere.