# Using an Interface for Collection<> generic type

Tags: c#, generics, collections, interface, casting

I have these types in c#

```
public class A : IA
{

}

public interface IA
{

}

public class B
{
    public B()
    {
        A = new List<A>(); //Where I have problem
    }

    public ICollection<IA> A { get; set; }
}
```

I've got this cast error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)

How can I do such things!

Comment: Look at @Daniel answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640738/c-sharp-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-listproduct-to-listiproduct) question.

Comment: [C# variance problem: Assigning List<Derived> as List<Base>](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2033912/284240)

Comment: And also here is a suggested workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832094/covariance-and-ilist/5832173#5832173

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't implicitly convert a List to List. If you want to do that, you need to decide whether the collection should contains A or IA.
Here is a fix:

```
public class B
{
    public B()
    {
        A = new List<IA>();
    }

    public ICollection<IA> A { get; set; }
}
```