# Unable to Map List collection Of One Class to another Class Model

Tags: c#

I have created a Mapper class that maps my Event Model to my EventEntity Model, these models have a List Property (Code Snippet shown below);

I came across this [C# - Cannot implicitly convert type List<Product> to List<IProduct>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640738/c-sharp-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-listproduct-to-listiproduct)

but I had difficulties in trying to implement the solution into my project.

```
//Event Model 

public List<EventData> EventData { get; set; }
```

```
//Event Entity Model

public List<EventDataEntity> EventData { get; set; }
```

My Mapper class (Code Snippet)

```
public class EventToEventEntityMapper : IMapper<Event, EventEntity>
    {
        public EventEntity Map(Event e)
        {
            
            var entity = new EventEntity
            {

                EventData = e.EventData.Select(Map).ToList() //Modified the code a per user comment
            };

            
            return entity;
        }
    }
```

```
//The Interface
public interface IMapper<TSource, TDestination>
    {
        TDestination Map(TSource entity);
    }
```

The error that I am getting

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0411  The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Select<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, int, TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly
```

Comment: Having a class with a function that converts one class type to other will not do that magically lists of your types to be converted automatically. Convert them manually or create two custom types based on these two list types and use [operator overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a mapping for your data objects as well.

Something like this:

```
public EventEntity Map(Event e)
{
    var entity = new EventEntity
    {
        EventData = e.EventData.Select(Map).ToList()
    };

    return entity;
}

public EventDataEntity Map(EventData e)
{
    var entity = new EventDataEntity
    {
        //...
    };

    return entity;
}
```

---

**Update**

After question edit, the approach needs to be changed slightly.

The above answer required both `Map` methods to be declared within the same class, however, as you are creating a generic `Mapper` interface, you would need to do something like this:

```
public class EventToEventEntityMapper : IMapper<Event, EventEntity>
{
    readonly IMapper<EventData, EventDataEntity> dataMapper;

    public EventToEventEntityMapper(IMapper<EventData, EventDataEntity> dataMapper)
    {
        this.dataMapper = dataMapper;
    }

    public EventEntity Map(Event e)
    {
        var entity = new EventEntity
        {
            EventData = e.EventData.Select(dataMapper.Map).ToList()
        };

        return entity;
    }
}

public class EventDataToEventDataEntityMapper : IMapper<EventData, EventDataEntity>
{
    public EventDataEntity Map(EventData e)
    {
        var entity = new EventDataEntity
        {
            //...
        };

        return entity;
    }
}
```

Then either inject your `EventDataToEventDataEntityMapper` or manually pass to the constructor:

```
new EventToEventEntityMapper(new EventDataToEventDataEntityMapper());
```

Comment: Thank you Johnathan Barclay for the help but I am getting this error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0411 The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Select<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

Comment: @dbjoe Are you sure? It compiles fine for me: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fpzUju

Comment: I think it maybe becuase my target framework is .net core 2.2 I am going to upgrade and see if it works.

Comment: @dbjoe Framework version _shouldn't_ really matter here. Using the .NET Framework 4.7.2 compiler on dotnetfiddle also compiles.

Comment: I have updated my post,  I am wondering if it becuase I am using an Interface ? IMapper<EventEntity, Event>